# Remove swiper JS slides after lazy load error

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm working on a page using [Swiper JS](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper) version 3.4.2. This page has a gallery with dynamic images coming from an external API.

Images are loaded using the [Lazy load component](https://swiperjs.com/api/#lazy). Valid image URLs load correctly, without any problems. But it seems there is no way to handle invalid image URLs.

I checked the Swiper JS [API docs](https://swiperjs.com/api/) and the project [issues](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues) on gitub. Looks like there is no event handler or any trigger to deal with invalid images. But I might be missing something...

Is there any way to remove the slide from the swiper js gallery if the image fails to load (e.g. 404 error)?

Comment: can you share your trying here? How you loading those those images?

Comment: I'm using the [Lazy Load component](https://swiperjs.com/api/#lazy). I'll build a jsfiddle sample and add it to the question.
Lazy loading is working fine. But I can't find a way to handle invalid images.

Comment: I am also looking for a built-in feature to handle this and then came across to this very old issue on GitHub. Seems the owner didn't have a plan to cover this.
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/1488